# Khan Academy, Example: Computing Partial Derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

Struggling in following this problem and it's solution.

Problem:

$f(x, 2) = 8x^2$

Solution:

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x, 2)=\frac{d}{dx}(8x^2)=16x$

$x=3$

$16(3)=48$

I got to the part where it's $8x^2$ - but then assumed the solution would be $8 * 3^2 = 72$

Guess what I am asking is why was the exponent moved down and multiplied instead of being used as an actual exponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x,2)=8x^2$ is the function that you want to take the derivative.

We compute the derivative and found

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x,2) = \frac{d}{dx}(8x^2) = 8(2)x^{2-1}=16x$$

Since you want to compute the derivative, we evaluate the derivative at $x=3$.

We have for a monomial, $x^n$,

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^n = nx^{n-1}$$

If you are interested in the value of a function, $f$, we compute $f(x)$.  If we are interested in the derivative, we compute $f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$.

Comment: Let's see if I follow, one should always multiply with the exponent, and reduce exponent by one? So if it instead were $x^3$ it would be $3x^2$ ?

Comment: It works for monomial, this is known as [power rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule). For other functions, some other rules apply.